# Jquery Deferred object issue when chaining .then

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm having an issue with my returned data for the chained then being the 1st deferred data. The first example works:

```
api.getData().done(function(data){
  api.getData2().done(
    function(data2){
      $.log('success', data2);
    });
  });
```

But the second example **SHOULD** work, having data2 for the second .then(), but for some reason its the same as data1.

```
api.getData().then(function(data1){
  return api.getData2();
}).then(
function(data2){
  $.log('success', data2);
});
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the code for `api.getData2`? If I remember correctly, `api.getData2` has to return a promise object for this to work correctly, and it also has to resolve the deferred object at some point. I've had this problem before myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So After some research [JQuery Deferred.Pipe](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/) I found out I can't chain .then, but instead need to use pipe like below (.pipe() is chainable):

```
api.getData().pipe(function(data1){
  return api.getData2();
}).then(
function(data2){
  $.log('success', data2);
});
```

Comment: additionally you can finish your chain with a .then (equivalent to both .done and .fail)

Answer (score 1):

[$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) will accept two asynchronous functions that returns a promise and execute the .then() function when both are done :

```
$.when( api.getData(), api.getData2() ).done(function(data, data2) {
    $.log('success', data2);
});
```

If for some reason (like needing the data) you need to perform `getData()` before `getData2()`, there really is no need for `.then()`, as your first example seems valid enough for that?